# How should an old API version be deprecated gracefully?

Tags: rest-api

When researching and reading about the WP REST API utilization I've seen many topics mentioned about how another version should be rolled out but nothing in the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/#return-value) regarding a return for a deprecated version.  Planning the life span of an API and how I should develop for each version I was unsure how I should fire a return indicating a newer version is pushed.

For example:

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
  register_rest_route( 'cpt/v1', '/all_posts/', array(
    'methods' => 'GET',
    'callback' => 'some_cpt',
  ) );
} );
```

if I were to change the route to:

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
  register_rest_route( 'cpt/v2', '/all_posts/', array(
    'methods' => 'GET',
    'callback' => 'some_cpt',
  ) );
} );
```

what should I properly pass through `v1` to indicate there is a new version?  Was thinking of using `WP_Error` as it is shown but I'm unsure the code return and where to implement the `WP_Error`:

```
return new WP_Error( 'new_version_needed', 'Deprecated version', array( 'status' => 303 ) );
```

or:

```
return new WP_Error( 'new_version_needed', 'Deprecated version', array( 'status' => 410 ) );
```

Comment: I would just simply return a string stating it is deprecated.

Comment: I understand that but where exactly and are you supposed to return it in the callback because what I've been led to believe the proper return should be done through `WP_Error` however, as linked, the documentation is limited.